# How to use mockito mock annotation in scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito

In java `@Mock` annotation can be used like below:

```
@Mock
private InsightHandleProvider handleProvider;
```

How to use the same annotation in Scala? It gives compilation error when tried to below:

```
class ThreadTest{
    @Mock
      val handleProvider:InsightHandleProvider 
    }
```

> Error:(16, 7) class ThreadTest needs to be abstract, since: it has 1
>   unimplemented member.

Comment: You might start by investigating whether `@Mock` has anything to do with the problem reported by the compiler.

Comment: In Java you have to call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` inside your test or use `MockitoTestRunner` in order to use those `@Mock` annotations. Are you doing the equivalent in Scala?

Answer (score 1):

Looking [here](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combining-scala-and-java.html) ... we find: *Existing annotations from Java frameworks can be used directly in Scala code. Any Java framework will see the annotations you write just as if you were writing in Java.*

So what you intend to do should actually work. Thus the problem is **not** that annotation, but (probably) the fact your variable `handleProvider` isn't initialized (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453406/error-class-animal-needs-to-be-abstract-since-it-has-5-unimplemented-members) for example).